framer-motion exit animation causing the entire list to re-render
I am trying to create a list that has enter & exit animations for all of it's items. I'm using framer-motion to achieve this. My code looks like this,
import Head from "next/head";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const listAnimation = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
    },
  },
}

const itemAnimation = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
  },
}

export default function Home() {
  let [list, setList] = useState(Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, __) => uuid()));

  function handleIncrement() {
    setList([...list, uuid()]);
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    setList(list.slice(0, -1));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Framer Lotion</title>
        <meta name="description" content="framer motion playground" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-black gap-4">
        <motion.ul
          variants={listAnimation}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          exit="hidden"
          className="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 list-none"
        >
          <AnimatePresence>
            {
              list.map((item, _) => (
                <motion.li
                  key={item}
                  variants={itemAnimation}
                  // initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
                  // animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                  // transition={{ duration: 0.1, delay: idx * 0.1 }}
                  className="p-5 rounded-lg bg-white/10 w-[400px]"
                />
              ))
            }
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.ul>
        <div className="flex gap-4">
          <button onClick={handleIncrement} className="px-4 py-2 text-white">Increment</button>
          <button onClick={handleDecrement} className="px-4 py-2 text-white">Decrement</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

In the above code, the increment button works fine and when the increment occurs, the new item animates in from initial state to animate state. The only problem is when I decrement and the list item is removed,

the item is abruptly removed the list
the entire list reanimates from initial to animate
the exit animation does not play for the item (i think this is because it is removed from the DOM)

How do I play the exit animation on decrement and prevent the entire list from re-animating itself when the item is removed from the list when the decrement button is presssed?
